# Parsing JavaScript Date string in Java

Tags: java, javascript, date

A JavaScript client sends some strings to my server, one of which comes in form of a JavaScript Date object's string representation.

Now, this JavaScript Date object has its own formatting and I was just wondering if there is a class that does the right conversion, as I am experiencing problems with the `SimpleDateFormatter`.

This is how a JavaScript Date string looks like: `Tue Feb 12 2013 21:12:28 GMT+0100 (CET)`

Comment: What are your problems with SimpleDateFormatter?

Comment: Try moment.js, trust me you'll get rid of all these annoying issues.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Best way to serialize the date in javascript is to use `toUTCString` (not just `toString()`); `toUTCString` will produce an rfc 822 date (in the same format as used by http). Then you can just use the following SimpleDateFormat pattern to parse it in java:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

Comment: If you're not in control of the producer of the date, and using `.toUTCString()` is not an option, you can use this format: `"EE MMM d y H:m:s 'GMT'Z (zz)"`

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) formatters for one main reason: they're thread-safe and immutable, so you can create one, keep it statically, and reuse it without any worries. Joda also allows easy specification of time zones etc. Of course, they end up creating Joda objects, which is another advantage IMO - I try to steer clear of Java's date/time API wherever possible.

Having said that, we'd need to know more about the format you're trying to parse, and what's going wrong with `SimpleDateFormatter`. (As a general rule, if you're "experiencing problems" with something and want those problems fixed, it helps to describe what the problems are, ideally with a short but complete program to demonstrate the problem.)

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Tue Feb 12 2013 21:12:28 GMT+0100 (CET)";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d u H:m:s VVZ (z)", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2013-02-12T21:12:28+01:00[Europe/Paris]
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ZgHHSN)

For any reason, if you need to convert this object of `ZonedDateTime` to an object of `java.util.Date`, you can do so as follows:

```
Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>